# Solve is taking days

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[n01/lambda1*Sin[alpha] + nl2/lambda2*Sin[beta] == 0 && n01/lambda1*Cos[alpha] + nl2/lambda2*Cos[beta] == nl3/lambda3 && Cos[theta - beta]^2/n02^2 + Sin[theta - beta]^2/nem2^2 == 1/nl2^2 && Cos[theta]^2/n03^2 + Sin[theta]^2/nem3^2 == 1/nl3^2, {theta, alpha, nl2, nl3}]
```

Why is it taking so long? I let it run for a day with no result. Is there anything I can do to accelerate the process?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want all possible solutions, or just one,  and do you have any constraints on the variables (like needing to be real or positive or the angles being between 0 and 2 pi)

Comment: Do you have numerical values for lamba1, as well as the other parametrs (ie, non-variables)